# update values everyday

Tags: trigger, sqlite

I have a table with 2 columns. `Days` is the days from `Start Date` to today.

How should Trigger be to automatically increase Days every day?

```
Start Date      Days  
19/07/17         19          
25/07/17         13
07/08/17         0
```

Answer (score 3):

Triggers only work on the rows which are affected by the statement causing the trigger to execute.

When you want to update a whole table, use a normal statement, not triggers.

When you have data, that can be easily calculated, don't store this in a table. Either you calculate it in your SELECT statement or create a view.

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW view_with_day_difference_calculated AS
SELECT start_date, TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, start_date, NOW()) AS days
FROM your_table;
```

Then all you have to do is this in the future.

```
SELECT * FROM view_with_day_difference_calculated;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add the days calculation as a computed column.

Comment: Computed columns are not supported by SQLite AFAIK.

Comment: Could you please describe this in more detail?

Comment: My apologies i thought this was for sql server.