# trigger to create new row every 30 days

Tags: trigger, datetime

How can I create trigger for table to insert a row every 30 day?

```
ID  Date        Days
1   10/7/2016    0
2   09/8/2016    30  
3   08/9/2016    60
```

Comment: is this question related to sqlite as is this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188721/update-values-everyday?

Answer (score 2):

A trigger is executed as result of a certain event (e.g insert/update/delete on a table). You need something like a job scheduler.

You did not specified the database. By example Oracle has something like:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(....
```